# The loudspeakers on my Sony Vaio (SVF1421L1EW) haven't worked since I installed Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sound

I am very pleased to have successfully installed Ubuntu on my new Sony Vaio laptop, but here's the thing, the loud speakers aren't working (they were working under Windows 8). But when I plug in a headset, the sound is perfect. Can you tell me how to get sound without having to use the headphones?
Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

This person reported the same issue (headphones work, speakers don't) on his Sony VAIO Fit 15E F15215SN/W using 64-bit Ubuntu 13.04. He updated an ALSA package from the Raring builds to get it working:

[How to fix the "built in speaker not working" issue in laptops with Ubuntu 13.04 (UEFI)](http://www.thegeekylinux.com/2013/07/how-to-fix-built-in-speaker-not-working.html)

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Once I worked how to install the programme I downloaded ("Open with Ubuntu Software Centre") it was fine. Many thanks for the ultra-swift answer !!! I'm ecstatic !